# Table cut by the page and not centered

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment

I'm writing a table that should be centered but it is not, and instead of fitting in the page it is cut by the page.

Here's the code:

```
\begin{table}[h]
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{|l|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
    \hline
    \textbf{benchmark} & \textbf{\#input} & \textbf{\#output} & \textbf{SOP} & \textbf{BCLP-1} & \textbf{BCLP-2} & \textbf{BCLP-3} & \textbf{BCLP-4} & \textbf{BCLP-5}\\
    \hline
    accpla.pla & 50 & 69 & 175 &  1457  & 1458 & XXX & YYY & ZZZ\\
    alu4.pla & 14 & 8 & 575 & 923  & 921 & XXX & YYY & ZZZ\\
```

and here it is the end result:
[image]

How can I make the table fit into the page, and appear at the center?

EDIT: the documentclass is `\documentclass[12pt]{article}`

EDIT2: if there is not an easy solution, can I at least rotate the table by 90° and make it fit horizontally?

Comment: Your table is too wide. Please provide a complete document that starts with `\documentclass` and ends with `\end{document}` and produces this table such that others can help you. Answers will depend on the layout of your document.

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat the column that is cut is the last one. Is there a way to force the table to the left until is centered despite of the documentclass?

Comment: Yes, `\centerline{ \begin{tabular}{|l|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|} ... \end{tabular}}` but you *really* don't want to go there. Instead rotate the elements of the first row.

Comment: Do you know how can I rotate it and put it horizontally?  At least it should fit that way

Comment: Yes, load `\usepackage{graphicx}` and use `\rotatebox`. A more detailed reply requires a *complete* document to test that what one has done is sufficient.

Comment: Yes, sorry but my document is scattered in multiple files and part of it are being generated by bash or python scripts and it is not easy to put all here. But I solved the problem replacing `table` with `sidewaystable` from the package `rotating`

Comment: In order to get an answers, please make your example code in your question compilable by adding the document as well as the relevant packages. Do you use the geometry package? If so, please also include these settings into your small example document. Without knowing the margins/textwidth of your document as well as the used font/font size, it is not really possible to give you ans sensible suggestions on how your table could fit into the textwidth. For a general overview you might have a look at  [My table doesn't fit; what are my options?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/332902/134144)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to squeeze the table inside the standard margins, if you want. I have reduced `tabcolsep` and removed vertical rules. Since the table was too wide due to the headers, I added the common part of the header on a line for itself, and reduced the fontsize. I assumed this did not change the meaning, but if I am wrong, this is not the path to go. If possible for you, you could also abbreviate `#input` and `#output` to `#in` and `#out`

The five last columns, I typeset with fixed width, using [array](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/array) and `w`-columns.

I have made three examples, one with vertical rules, and one without and one with the headings you have in your table, except that I have removed the bold and reduced the font size to reduce the size of the header:

**Example 1: booktabs version**

In addition I did the usual thing to make the table readable: [boooktabs](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/booktabs) rules, grouping the rows by small white space, removing the left and right side bearings (`@{}`).

If your table has a caption, I suggest using [threeparttable](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/threeparttable), which automatically ensure that table and caption is of same with, if the caption is multiline. [caption](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/caption) will help you formatting the captions. And column with only numbers should be right aligned (col 2 to col 6):

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{array, booktabs, caption, threeparttable}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0.5em}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\centering
\begin{threeparttable}
\caption{A table is much nicer if you use booktabs and remove vertical rules. threepartable ensure that caption and table is of the same length}
\begin{tabular}{@{}lrrr*{2}{wr{\dimexpr(1.15cm-(2\tabcolsep))}}*{3}{wc{\dimexpr(1.15cm-(2\tabcolsep))}}}
\toprule
&&&&\multicolumn{5}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{5.71cm}}{\small\bfseries BCLP}\\ \cmidrule(l{\tabcolsep}){5-9}
\small\textbf{Benchmark} & \small\textbf{\#input} & \small\textbf{\#output} & \small\textbf{SOP} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\small\bfseries 1} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\small\bfseries 2} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\small\bfseries 3} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\small\bfseries 4} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\small\bfseries 5}\\
\midrule
accpla.pla & 50 & 69 & 175 &  1457  & 1458 & XXX & YYY & ZZZ\\
alu4.pla & 14 & 8 & 575 & 923  & 921 & XXX & YYY & ZZZ\\
accpla.pla & 50 & 69 & 175 &  1457  & 1458 & XXX & YYY & ZZZ\\
alu4.pla & 14 & 8 & 575 & 923  & 921 & XXX & YYY & ZZZ\\
accpla.pla & 50 & 69 & 175 &  1457  & 1458 & XXX & YYY & ZZZ\\\addlinespace
alu4.pla & 14 & 8 & 575 & 923  & 921 & XXX & YYY & ZZZ\\
accpla.pla & 50 & 69 & 175 &  1457  & 1458 & XXX & YYY & ZZZ\\
alu4.pla & 14 & 8 & 575 & 923  & 921 & XXX & YYY & ZZZ\\
accpla.pla & 50 & 69 & 175 &  1457  & 1458 & XXX & YYY & ZZZ\\
alu4.pla & 14 & 8 & 575 & 923  & 921 & XXX & YYY & ZZZ\\\addlinespace
accpla.pla & 50 & 69 & 175 &  1457  & 1458 & XXX & YYY & ZZZ\\
alu4.pla & 14 & 8 & 575 & 923  & 921 & XXX & YYY & ZZZ\\
accpla.pla & 50 & 69 & 175 &  1457  & 1458 & XXX & YYY & ZZZ\\
alu4.pla & 14 & 8 & 575 & 923  & 921 & XXX & YYY & ZZZ\\
accpla.pla & 50 & 69 & 175 &  1457  & 1458 & XXX & YYY & ZZZ\\
\bottomrule    
\end{tabular}
\end{threeparttable}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

**Example 2: vertical rules**

In this example, I had to decrease the `tabcolsep` further to `0.411em`, because the vertical rules need the side bearings. I also added 2 pt to the rows height to avoid the collision between horizontal rules and the content of he cells.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{array}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\setlength{\extrarowheight}{2pt}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0.413em}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|l|*{5}{r|}*{3}{c|}}
\hline
&&&&\multicolumn{5}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{5cm}|}{\small\bfseries BCLP}\\ \cline{5-9}
\small\textbf{Benchmark} & \small\textbf{\#input} & \small\textbf{\#output} & \small\textbf{SOP} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\small\bfseries 1} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\small\bfseries 2} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\small\bfseries 3} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\small\bfseries 4} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\small\bfseries 5}\\
\hline
accpla.pla & 50 & 69 & 175 &  1457  & 1458 & XXX & YYY & ZZZ\\
alu4.pla & 14 & 8 & 575 & 923  & 921 & XXX & YYY & ZZZ\\
accpla.pla & 50 & 69 & 175 &  1457  & 1458 & XXX & YYY & ZZZ\\
alu4.pla & 14 & 8 & 575 & 923  & 921 & XXX & YYY & ZZZ\\
accpla.pla & 50 & 69 & 175 &  1457  & 1458 & XXX & YYY & ZZZ\\[1ex]
alu4.pla & 14 & 8 & 575 & 923  & 921 & XXX & YYY & ZZZ\\
accpla.pla & 50 & 69 & 175 &  1457  & 1458 & XXX & YYY & ZZZ\\
alu4.pla & 14 & 8 & 575 & 923  & 921 & XXX & YYY & ZZZ\\
accpla.pla & 50 & 69 & 175 &  1457  & 1458 & XXX & YYY & ZZZ\\
alu4.pla & 14 & 8 & 575 & 923  & 921 & XXX & YYY & ZZZ\\[1ex]
accpla.pla & 50 & 69 & 175 &  1457  & 1458 & XXX & YYY & ZZZ\\
alu4.pla & 14 & 8 & 575 & 923  & 921 & XXX & YYY & ZZZ\\
accpla.pla & 50 & 69 & 175 &  1457  & 1458 & XXX & YYY & ZZZ\\
alu4.pla & 14 & 8 & 575 & 923  & 921 & XXX & YYY & ZZZ\\
accpla.pla & 50 & 69 & 175 &  1457  & 1458 & XXX & YYY & ZZZ\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

**Example 3: With original table headings**

`tabolsep` is further decreased. Fontsize in header smaller.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{array}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\setlength{\extrarowheight}{2pt}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0.3em}
\centering
\rule{\linewidth}{2pt}
\bigskip
\begin{tabular}{|l|*{5}{r|}*{3}{c|}}
\hline
\footnotesize  Benchmark & \footnotesize \#input & \footnotesize \#output & \footnotesize SOP & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\footnotesize BCLP-1} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\footnotesize BCLP-2} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\footnotesize BCLP-3} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\footnotesize BCLP-4} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\footnotesize BCLP-5}\\
\hline
accpla.pla & 50 & 69 & 175 &  1457  & 1458 & XXX & YYY & ZZZ\\
alu4.pla & 14 & 8 & 575 & 923  & 921 & XXX & YYY & ZZZ\\
accpla.pla & 50 & 69 & 175 &  1457  & 1458 & XXX & YYY & ZZZ\\
alu4.pla & 14 & 8 & 575 & 923  & 921 & XXX & YYY & ZZZ\\
accpla.pla & 50 & 69 & 175 &  1457  & 1458 & XXX & YYY & ZZZ\\[1ex]
alu4.pla & 14 & 8 & 575 & 923  & 921 & XXX & YYY & ZZZ\\
accpla.pla & 50 & 69 & 175 &  1457  & 1458 & XXX & YYY & ZZZ\\
alu4.pla & 14 & 8 & 575 & 923  & 921 & XXX & YYY & ZZZ\\
accpla.pla & 50 & 69 & 175 &  1457  & 1458 & XXX & YYY & ZZZ\\
alu4.pla & 14 & 8 & 575 & 923  & 921 & XXX & YYY & ZZZ\\[1ex]
accpla.pla & 50 & 69 & 175 &  1457  & 1458 & XXX & YYY & ZZZ\\
alu4.pla & 14 & 8 & 575 & 923  & 921 & XXX & YYY & ZZZ\\
accpla.pla & 50 & 69 & 175 &  1457  & 1458 & XXX & YYY & ZZZ\\
alu4.pla & 14 & 8 & 575 & 923  & 921 & XXX & YYY & ZZZ\\
accpla.pla & 50 & 69 & 175 &  1457  & 1458 & XXX & YYY & ZZZ\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've solved the problem by rotating the table. In order to do so I've replaced

```
\begin{table}...\end{table}
```

with

```
\begin{sidewaystable}...\end{sidewaystable}
```

from the package `rotating`

If someone has an answer to say how can I shrink to fit the table without rotating please say it here. It would still be the solution I prefer.

Comment: The standard solution consists in reducing the value of `\tabcolsep` (6pt by default) and/or reducing the font size (not too much, so it remains readable – in my opinion, `\footnotesize` is the lower limit).

Comment: @GerardoZinno I think I solved the problem without rotating the table.